# Get everything but dashes at the beginning - regEx in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build my regular expression, but I've failed.
I'm trying to get everything after single or double dash (you can try it [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?33k4e)):

```
var regEx = /(?<=[-{1,2}])[^-]\S*/g;
```

It works just fine, but it selects even if we have 3+ dashes too. I've tried something like `/(?<=^[-{1,2}])[^-]\S*/g` and `/(?<=\b[-{1,2}])[^-]\S*/g`, but then it crashes at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm surprised it does not throw an error (well, it throws an error in Chrome). JavaScript does not support lookbehinds. In any case, you are not anchoring the expression.

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `^-{1,2}([^-]*)$`?

Comment: @FelixKling I'm sorry, I was trying to build it on this site so long, that I even haven't tried it in js and yes, it throws error. I thought it supports it just like Ruby.

Comment: @cha0site I want to return the cleaned from dashes value in single regEx, actually this was my first expression and it seems to be my choise.

Comment: So... `^(-{1,2})([^-]*)$` would do what you want then?

Comment: Really close, the only thing is that `[^-]*` is only for the first character after single/double dashes, so `[^-]*` should be `[^-]\S*` like in my failed example. Anyway thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `javascript` **doesn't** support `lookbehind`

---

You can use this regex with `multiline` option

```
^-{1,2}(?!-)(\S*)
```

After this you can use **group 1** to access the required match..

Comment: I didn't know that before. This is exactly what I did at first, thanks.